# GroupBy, OrderByDescending using Lambda in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a collection and I need to order it by descending date(`DateProcessed` field) using `Linq`, first I am grouping by two possible Keys: `Booked` or `Empty`. But the data it's not being ordered..

This is my expression:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassMongo>> sub = Model.MyCollection.GroupBy(f => f.IsBooked ? "Booked" : "Empty").OrderByDescending(f => f.FirstOrDefault().DateProcessed);
```

I'm confused because I am grouping first, I know that after grouping the collection is splitted in two(`Booked` and `Empty`) so I am not sure how to handle the sorting because I am grouping first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying in-memory collection, then just place ordering before grouping:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClassMongo>> sub = 
    Model.MyCollection
         .OrderByDescending(f => f.DateProcessed)
         .GroupBy(f => f.IsBooked ? "Booked" : "Empty");
```

Items within each group will be sorted by `DateProcessed`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to first Group by and then sort the results within the Group. you can try some thing like below

```
Model.MyCollection
    .GroupBy(f => f.IsBooked, 
             (f, g) => new{Key=f.DateProcessed, Group = g.OrderByDescending(c=>c.IsBooked)})
    .OrderByDescending(f => f.Key);
```

PS: Code may have syntax issue not tested but the idea should be to create the key withing each group so we can order by